# What ports are used by an application

Tags: linux, networking, port, tcp, diagnostic

I'm testing an application which opens its own ports (acts as a server for these ports, hence listens at that ports) and where the same application connects to ports bound by other applications (acts as client for these ports).

I would like to get an overview as to which ports the application creates and to which applications and ports it connects to.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can use `netstat` for this. See the example (I grepped for `ssh`):

```
netstat -putan | grep ssh
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1725/sshd
tcp        0      0 1.2.3.4:45734           1.2.3.5:22              ESTABLISHED 2491/ssh
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN      1725/sshd
```

**Explanation:**

I often use the parameters `-putan` (because they are simple to remember).

- `-p`: show the PIDs of the application/process
- `-u`: show udp ports/connections
- `-t`: show tcp ports/connections
- `-a`: show both listening and non-listening sockets
- `-n`: numeric output (don't do DNS lookups for hostnames etc.)

In the output above, you see that there is an ssh daemon process (`sshd`) with PID `1725` listening at port `22` on all network interfaces (`0.0.0.0`). Also there is an ssh client process (PID `2491`) connected to the IP-address `1.2.3.5` at port number `22`, my IP-address is `1.2.3.4` and my external port is `45734`. You see that the connection is established. Therefore I'm logged in via `ssh`.

Comment: An established TCP connection on port 22 does not indicate successful authentication. TCP must be established before authentication in either direction can occur.

Comment: @Puddingfox yes true, we could better say "I'm connected to that port", but for comprehension I said "i'm logged in", because it's more illustrative.

Comment: hehe... [`-putan'](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vladimir_Putin) I'm so tempted to correct this minor spelling error ;)

Comment: Why use obsolete utilities when modern ones are available? *ss -lntp* is the  utility provided by the *iproute2* suite.

Comment: This post did not age well. lol

Answer (score 7):

Another tool that can do this is [`lsof`](http://linux.die.net/man/8/lsof):

```
# lsof -i -a -p 1981
COMMAND  PID USER   FD   TYPE DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
sshd    1981 root    3u  IPv4    917      0t0  TCP host.example.com:ssh (LISTEN)
# lsof -i -a -p 1981 -n
COMMAND  PID USER   FD   TYPE DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
sshd    1981 root    3u  IPv4    917      0t0  TCP 10.1.2.3:ssh (LISTEN)
# lsof -i -a -p 1981 -n -P
COMMAND  PID USER   FD   TYPE DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
sshd    1981 root    3u  IPv4    917      0t0  TCP 10.1.2.3:22 (LISTEN)
#
```

Options used are as follows:

- `-i` to print out internet ports open by a process
- `-a` to cause all options to be AND-ed
- `-p 1981` to show output for process 1981
- `-n` to inhibit hostname lookup and show IP instead
- `-P` to inhibit service lookup and show port number instead

`lsof` has the advantage that you can specify the process to check rather than having to grep it out of larger output.  `netstat` is more reliably available on systems, although `lsof` is becoming more standard than it used to be.

Comment: I would like to run this command before launching the application I wish to monitor but can I establish what pid an application will get before starting it?

Comment: @Baz, if you want to monitor an application as it starts up (e.g., before you know it's PID), you should try the `strace` solution that @olivecoder suggested.

Answer (score 4):

We have already good answers but they only list the ports that are open at the moment the command runs.

`strace` is the right tool to monitor the connections opened during the application lifetime:

```
strace -e socket,connect,close -f -o hipchat.strace.txt hipchat
```

The output would show you additional information like UDP requests and opened but closed connections.

Answer (score 3):

`ss` utility from [iproute](http://kernel.org/pub/linux/utils/net/iproute2/) package for Linux

Answer (score 0):

`ss -a4 | less`

I'm assuming you're speaking about IPv4... If not, you can replace the 4 in the preceeding command with 6. The -a parameter is to show all ports (listening and non). You can add -n to the parameters if you don't want to resolve names in the display.